# Electron forge throws '.../python3.8" links out of the package' error when making with asar enabled on Mac

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager, electron-forge

I am trying to distribute an electron project. So I follow the official guide and use electron-forge. Here is my config.forge:

```
"config": {
    "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": {
        "asar":true,
        "ignore":[
          "^/[.].+$",
          "^/app/src$",
          "^.*/tsconfig([.].*)?[.]json",
          "^/angular[.]json",
          "^/frontend$",
          "^/build$"
        ]
      },
      "makers": [
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-squirrel",
          "config": {
            "name": "my-app"
          }
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-zip",
          "platforms": [
            "darwin"
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-deb",
          "config": {}
        },
        {
          "name": "@electron-forge/maker-rpm",
          "config": {}
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

It builds fine without `asar:true`. But if I add `asar:true`, it throws this error:

```
An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: /var/folders/k1/12r0xrxd01n7zgfpqfxppqm80000gn/T/electron-packager/darwin-arm64/my-app-darwin-arm64/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules/@serialport/bindings-cpp/build/node_gyp_bins/python3: file "../../../../../../../../../../../../../Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8" links out of the package

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
```

Answer (score 4):

A [fix for this](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/2713) has been recently merged in node-gyp. While we wait for this to be upgraded there is a workaround, if you're using electron forge, you can remove the `node_gyp_bins` directory in a [hook](https://www.electronforge.io/config/hooks) in your electron forge config. Something like this worked for me (replacing module name with the offending module).

```js
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('node:fs/promises');
{
....
hooks: {
     packageAfterPrune: async (_config, buildPath) => {
       const gypPath = path.join(
         buildPath,
         'node_modules',
         'moduleName',
         'build',
         'node_gyp_bins'
       );
       await fs.rm(gypPath, {recursive: true, force: true});
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the only answer that works with electron forge, since changing the version of anything else is a much larger headache than installing this hook.

Comment: Thanks this worked!  I guess it still isn't fixed.

Comment: I have put this 

hooks: {
     packageAfterPrune: async (_config, buildPath) => {
       const gypPath = path.join(
         buildPath,
         'node_modules',
         '@serialport',
  'bindings-cpp',
         'build',
  'node_gyp_bins',
       );
       await fs.rm(gypPath, {recursive: true, force: true});
    }
  }

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be caused by this node-gyp issue: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/2713

Node-Gyp now creates links to the detect binary versions, apparently to help it consistently use the same versions during builds. These are left after the build finishes, and they point outside the project directory (e.g. to `/usr/bin/python`). That makes various tools refuse to bundle your node_modules with these links present.

This is really a bug in node-gyp imo, but fixing that may take some time. You could attempt to contribute a fix for that bug in the node-gyp project yourself, or in the meantime you can work around this by deleting all `node_gyp_bins` folders in your node_modules before building.